# Passive Attenuator + Voltage divider to level shift input signal without violating KCL

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, analog, voltage-divider, kirchhoffs-laws

I have a 7vpp voltage input signal centered at 0V, so +/-3.5V. I wish to turn this into a 2Vpp signal centered at 1.65V, so 0.65V to 2.65V. To start with I have a passive attenuator to give an attenuation of 1/3.5, changing my +/-3.5V signal to +/-1V signal. My plan is to then add a level shift stage with an op amp to shift +1.65V, this will move +/-1V to 0.65 to 2.65 range. My problem is that my original circuit design had the passive attenuator, which is just a voltage divider, feed into another voltage divider with an offset value of +1.65V for the level shift, but I went over it with my professor and he showed me how it violates Kirchhoff's Current Law since the current at that node will not be 0. So I am wondering if I can maybe use an op amp in between the passive attenuator and the level shift voltage divider like in my attached picture. My VDD is 3.3V also. [image] After the level shift the 0.65V - 2.65V signal will be fed into a differential op amp to convert from single ended to differential.

Comment: Split the R to GND  in your 1/3.5 attenuator (why oh why no numbered components?) into two resistors, each double its value. Return one to GND, one to a clean 3.3V. Done. (Buffer that if the next step needs a low source impedance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work. You would need 4Vp-p at the op-amp output to get 2Vp-p at the output, since RA||RB = 10K, and your Vcc is only 3.3V so  you can only get less than 3.3Vp-p.

You can do this entire thing with three resistors (such as 10K, 17.5K, 23.33K) if the input signal is low impedance.

Maybe you misunderstood your instructor who was pointing out an error in your calculations.

Comment: The impedance should be under 50ohms if I understood my professor correctly. I am not sure if this is in the range of low or high impedance. In the case of using the three resistors you mentioned do you mean that I would run the 10k into the divider where ra = 17.5k and rb = 23.33k?

Comment: You should be able to calculate the effect and compare it  with the requirements. As to which resistor is which, this is your homework problem and I would hate to deprive you of the sense of satisfaction from figuring it out yourself. When you do you can use those numbers as a cross check though.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. Just one last question and I'm sorry if this seems like I'm trying to just have somebody else solve my problem for me, but my design in terms of using an op amp between the attenuation and level shift stage to keep in line with KCL is alright? My issue lies in my calculations to choose resistor values?

Comment: I forgot to mention the Ra||Rb = 10k was my resistor value choice along with the single 10k, they are not defined by the project.

Comment: KCL is always true.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was able to solve it with just 3 resistors like you said, and after simulating it I am very close I just need to make some corrections in calculations.